# Tracing inheritable permission in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I have a bunch of IDs which has write access to a particular OU in Active Directory. This access is inherited through security groups.

Due to the large number of security groups these IDs are in, I can't determine which one provided the write access to these IDs. Is there a quick way of finding out?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://vanhybrid.com/2012/02/25/working-with-sids-in-powershell/) shows a posibility of getting the name of a group or user account in you only have the SID.